# Phoenix Elixir Canary/Canada undefined function can?3 when trying to access inside template view

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to use [Coherence](https://github.com/smpallen99/coherence) together with [Canary](https://github.com/cpjk/canary) by following this sample [coherence_demo with canary](https://github.com/smpallen99/coherence_demo/tree/canary).

Except that I am using `Phoenix v1.3.0` while the sample above (on its `canary`'s `branch`) is still using earlier version of `Phoenix`

Seems that I've got it to work (definitely working through/inside controllers) except that I cannot access `Canary`'s or `Canada`'s `can?3` function from inside the (layout) template view.

Giving me this error:

`== Compilation error in file lib/my_project_web/views/layout_view.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/my_project_web/templates/layout/app.html.eex:20: undefined function can?/3
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1338: :lists.foreach/2
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:121: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1`

my `abilities.ex` file is inside `lib` directory like so: `./lib/abilities.ex`

What is possibily wrong? How to register `Canada`/`Canary` so that it can be used within template view?

Comment: It's off topic but coherence is terrible and you'd be better off not using it

Comment: Do you have another suggestion?  Is [Guardian](https://github.com/ueberauth/guardian) better from your experience?

Have just passed in my mind that probably better to ask directly on [Canary's Github Issues](https://github.com/cpjk/canary/issues) because I think this is a specific `Canary` problem instead of `Canary` - `Coherence` combination.

Comment: Have you added `import Canada.Can` like this to the `view` function in `web.ex` like this: https://github.com/smpallen99/coherence_demo/blob/a59db0cdf7a4c27c9afc9c059a36facef8282a87/web/web.ex#L55?

Comment: Oh my! That's it! I have missed it although had been following the [exact commit here](https://github.com/smpallen99/coherence_demo/commit/b193c4de4ad6119a1825fb015b9f112343cdee39#diff-75c165bdf904a7a8b835dd36f41e6a93).

It is actually at the most bottom, that I have missed.

Thank you.

If you want, please put the answer below, so that I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`can?` is defined in the `Canada.Can` module. The error message suggests your view doesn't import that module. The sample project you linked to imports that module in all the views by adding the import to the `view` function in `web/web.ex`, which you probably forgot:

[In `web/web.ex`](https://github.com/smpallen99/coherence_demo/blob/a59db0cdf7a4c27c9afc9c059a36facef8282a87/web/web.ex#L55):

```
defmodule CoherenceDemo.Web do
  def view do
    quote do
      ...

      import Canada.Can
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is it! This fixes my problem. Thank you.